# List with duplicates to without duplicates

Tags: java, collections

I have a list with duplicate values.

```
List<valFile> isList = valBo.findId();
```

isList has values like {100, 100, 100, 102, 105, 105}

I want to remove these duplicates and use the same list with no duplicates. I tried set but dont know how to use the same list without duplicates.

Comment: Why not use an implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same list?

Comment: If the order of elements is not a requirement, you should be using Set in the first place to store the values.

Comment: Just as a note, according to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), type names like `valFile` should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `LinkedHashSet` to maintain the ordering and add all the items from the List. The duplicates will be discarded:

```
Set<valFile> set = new LinkedHashSet<valFile>(isList);
```

Then add it back to a list:

```
List<valFile> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<valFile>(set);
```

Comment: it is not allowing me to do set.addAll(isList). I get a message saying addAll(List) cannot invoke addAll(Collection) in set.

Comment: @JNPW I edited the answer but Set.addAll(list) should also work for you.

Comment: Now i get HashSet(List) cannot invoke HashSet(Collection).

Comment: @JNPW Something is wrong with your setup - what IDE are you using? What is your java version

Comment: The above is valid Java code, not sure why it is not working for you? Is the message an error, exception or warning?

Comment: What's the fully-qualified name of the List class you're using?  Is it `java.util.List` or something else?

Comment: @JNPW Do you have a compiler level that your IDE is bound to? Or a configuration that trips warnings when it encounters this code?

Comment: I get this when i save the class file. It shows the red underline.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a set and dump back to a list.

```
List<valFile> unique = new ArrayList<valFile>(new HashSet<valFile>(islist));
Collections.sort(unique);
```

Or if you have a good comparator, you can use a TreeSet

```
Set<valFile> unique = new TreeSet<valFile>(isList);
```

If you absolutely MUST use the same list (perhaps because there are other references to it somewhere), your best bet is to clear it.

```
List<valFile> unique = new ArrayList<valFile>(new HashSet<valFile>(islist));
Collections.sort(unique);
isList.clear();
isList.addAll(unique);
```

Comment: One can use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet` to maintain the original order of the elements (if this is a requirement).

Comment: If you can guarantee they're sorted going in, `LinkedHashSet` is an excellent solution.

Comment: You can use `LinkedHashSet` in any case, the list does not need to be sorted. It will still remove duplicates and keep the elements in the original order.